# Shrink image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dhtml

I need to shrink the image that was kept in div background-image using javascript.for that image four's side having rounded corner.

Is it possible in javascript?

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You *can't* resize backgrounds with JS.

You *can* split the image up into 4 corner images and nest divs to show them all:

```
<div style="background:url(tl.jpg) top left no-repeat">
    <div style="background:url(tr.jpg) top right no-repeat">
        <div style="background:url(bl.jpg) bottom left no-repeat">
            <div style="background:url(br.jpg) bottom right no-repeat">
                content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course you can simplify that if you div only grows on one axis:

```
<div style="background:url(top.jpg) top no-repeat">
    <div style="background:url(bottom.jpg) bottom no-repeat">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just thought about the same solution... In addition, I created a small draft, showing the splited background as well as the parts which have to be repeated: http://img24.imageshack.us/my.php?image=stackoverflowcssbgresiz.png

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support the resizing of a background image.

If you're just looking for rounded corners, there are a wide variety of solutions available that use various combinations of HTML, CSS and Javascript.

[Google: Rounded Corners](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=rounded+corners)

Comment: CSS does support it, browsers don't support the CSS 3 specifications that has the background-size rule.

Answer (score 0):

CSS 3 has the background-size property which would let you do this, but it's not supported in most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern browsers will let you round the corners of an element without resorting to background images. Check out the following CSS styles...

```
-moz-border-radius:4px; 
border-radius:4px; 
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
```

Each of these will give you a 4pixel radius. The first in Mozilla browsers (eg Firefox), the second is newer css3 browsers and the last in Safari et al.